Th substitution property of modules implies the cancellation property of modules
We say that a module $M_R$ satisfies the internal cancellation property (or $M$ is internally cancellable) if whenever $M=A\oplus X = B\oplus Y$ with $A \cong B$, then $X \cong Y$. We say that $M$ satisfies the cancellation property (or $M$ is cancellable) if $M\oplus X \cong M\oplus Y$ implies $X\cong Y$ for any right $R$-modules $X,Y$. The module $M$ is said to have the substitution property if for every module $N$ with decompositions $N=A\oplus B=A'\oplus B'$ with $A\cong M\cong A'$, there exists a submodule $C\subseteq N$ such that $N=C\oplus B=C \oplus B'$.
It is clear that the substitution property implies the internal cancellation property. Most textbooks state that the substitution property implies the cancellation property. For instance, on page 13 of this paper

T.Y. Lam, 2004. A crash course on stable range, cancellation, substitution and exchange. Journal of Algebra and Its Applications, 3(03), pp.301-343.

the author states that Substitution $\Longrightarrow$ Cancellation.
How can I prove this?. It is not clear for me.
